# Need to answer half questions automatically on script

Tags: shell

Is it possible to answer first few or a part of questions automatically and rest manually?
I am connecting to a VPN daily which gives first prompt to say "yes" or "no", second one to choose a group and third one to input username. Upto three questions, answers will be same. Fourth prompt is a physical RSA token input and fifth one is a password.

When I script it with an input file for first three questions (eg; ./script < inputfile), the connection exits as below.

GROUP: [xxxx|abcdgroup01|sssgroup01|sssssgroup01z]:Please enter your username and password.
Username:Password:
fgets (stdin): Inappropriate ioctl for device

This is happening because the script is not getting the fourth answer from the input file.

Out of five inputs, four are static ones and the fourth one is a dynamic one. 
How do I manage to enter fourth input manually ?

Please help; Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you just create a temporary file that has all the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways, but for your case, your approach doesn't seem to be so bad.

If you really want the user to see the original prompt from script.sh, you would have to create an *expect* program to drive your script; see the man-page for `expect`.

If you are permitted to change script.sh, you could add the possibility to supply certain parameters from the outside (a file, or an environment variable) and only ask for those parameters which are not supplied. This would IMO be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this method and it seems working !

{ echo yes; echo xxxxx; echo xxxx; read rsa; echo $rsa; echo xxxx; } | ./script.sh

Any other way ?